# Adding an external jar to GWT

Tags: java, gwt, jar

Im trying to bind the Amazon Web Services SDK jar library to GWT so it can be used in my project. I followed this [example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GWTModules/article.html) which converts a simple project into a jar and adds it to gwt for use. So in my case I created a jar file from aws-java-sdk-1.10.32.jar (downloaded) and added a AmazonAWS.gwt.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "//gwt-module/" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6.2/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">

<module rename-to='amazonaws'>
<!-- GWT Core -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />

<!-- translate the client to javascript -->
<source path='amazonaws' />
</module>
```

I made sure to inherit it on my application gwt.xml file...

```
<inherits name="com.AmazonAWS"/>
```

And I double checked the Jars directory path consists to what I created, in the case of the jar file, all packaged java classes root from com/amazonaws/ (com/ is where I placed the AmazonAWS.gwt.xml file)

I still get the same error though, `Line 24: No source code is available for type com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider; did you forget to inherit a required module?`

Am I missing anything? any help would be appreciated

Comment: Most important aspect: did you add the Java source to the JAR? GWT compiler parses Java files, not class files.

Comment: You are right, I was not using the .java files but the class files from the jar package, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to add the Java source code to the JAR, as the GWT compiler operates on Java source-code level and not on bytecode (class files).